# Multiple Images upload with different titles

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Requirement is. I will be uploading 3-4 images at a time through `FileUpload`. Each Image will have its own `Title`, `Descriptions` etc.

Now my issue is that, whenever uploading I have given a `title` column for the images. But when I upload 3-4 Images the `title` and `description` is going same for all the images.

Here Is my **HTML** for the Image Uploading via `FileUpload`.

```
 <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <asp:label cssclass="control-label" id="Label1" runat="server">Image Title</asp:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:textbox id="txtImagetitle" cssclass="form-control" runat="server" validationgroup="AddNew"></asp:textbox>
                <asp:requiredfieldvalidator cssclass="error-class" id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                    controltovalidate="txtImagetitle" errormessage="Please add the image title" validationgroup="AddNew"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <asp:label cssclass="control-label" id="Label2" runat="server">Image description</asp:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:textbox id="txtImagedesc" cssclass="form-control" runat="server" validationgroup="AddNew"></asp:textbox>
                <asp:requiredfieldvalidator cssclass="error-class" id="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"
                    controltovalidate="txtImagedesc" errormessage="Please add the image description"
                    validationgroup="AddNew"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <asp:label cssclass="control-label" id="Label3" runat="server">Image upload</asp:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:fileupload id="FileUpload1" runat="server" allowmultiple="true" />
                <asp:requiredfieldvalidator cssclass="error-class" id="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"
                    controltovalidate="FileUpload1" errormessage="Please add the gallery date" validationgroup="AddNew"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please suggest what to do in this case when uploading multiple images how to set different titles for different Images.

**UPDATED CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/" + filename));

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))

                if (Request.QueryString["Id"] != null)
                {
                    string Id = Request.QueryString["Id"];

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = " Update tbl_galleries_stack SET gallery_id=@gallery_id,img_title=@img_title,img_desc=@img_desc,img_path=@img_path, IsDefault=@IsDefault Where Id=@Id";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gallery_id", ddlgallery.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_title", txtImagetitle.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_desc", txtImagedesc.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_path", filename);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsDefault", chkDefault.Checked);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Gallery updated sucessfully');window.location ='csrgalleriesstack.aspx';", true);
                }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/" + filename));
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_galleries_stack (gallery_id,img_title,img_desc,img_path,IsDefault) values(@gallery_id,@img_title, @img_desc, @img_path,@IsDefault)", conn);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@gallery_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlgallery.SelectedValue;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtImagetitle.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtImagedesc.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = filename;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@IsDefault", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkDefault.Checked;
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Gallery added sucessfully');window.location ='csrgalleriesstack.aspx';", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste your code-behind

Comment: @naveen: added the codebehind, see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can give different title / description as you have given no option to provide it. Period.

---

You are forced to use *multiple* fileupload controls. This is also tricky because `asp:FileUpload` controls *wont maintain* their state after postback.

So, the solution I can see is a two-part one. Create two panels and hide the second panel at page load

**Part 1**
Place a label and textbox and button like this in the first panel in your page. 
[image: Panel 1]
When the user enters a value, say 10, and fires `EnterButton_click` close Panel1 and open Panel2.

**Part 2**

On Panel 2, place a GridView like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="ImagesGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No">
            <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DisplayIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="flUpload" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="SaveButton_Click"/>
```

Now on the Enter buttons click event on Panel 1, write this.

```
// the idea is to create an empty gridview with number of rows client selected
protected void EnterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //in this, 10 has been entered    
    var imageCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtImageCount.Text);
    //var list = new List<string>();

    //for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    //{
    //    list.Add(string.Empty);
    //}
    var list = new List<string>(10);
    list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(String.Empty, imageCount));
    ImagesGrid.DataSource = list;
    ImagesGrid.DataBind();

    //TO DO: hide panel1 and make panel2 visible
}
```

So on clicking enter, you will get an empty gridview with ten rows.
[image: Panel 2]

Now fill the rows in the GridView, *do validation* and hit Save. On Save Button click event, you can access the WebControls like this.

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in ImagesGrid.Rows)
    {
        var title = row.FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
        var description = row.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox;
        var imageFile = row.FindControl("flUpload") as FileUpload;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(imageFile.FileName);
        imageFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/" + filename));
        //TO DO: write save routine
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented your steps, but it is always opening the second panel i.e `gridview` with Ten Rows. How to set that dynamically on the basis of values entered into the textbox ?

Comment: I got that, In place of that, i wrote `imageCount`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only have one set of inputs tied to a single file upload with multiple turned on.

You will either want to turn off multiple and allow the user to add reported sets of those images, or have the editing of title, etc happen in a gridview with the upload.

You could also support a"holding cell " where they upload and then must enter that information before you actually save it to your data store.

Comment: I want the multiple upload option.!!

Comment: There's no way to have the end user enter that information then unless you design a holding cell.

Comment: Okay, is there any other way ?

Comment: Multiple upload controls. One file per upload control. Allow the user to add as many as they want.

Comment: I dont want that way, client wont go again and again to upload that. They want the `Multiple` option

Comment: OK then you get one uploaded title.

Comment: @NadeemKhan, tim is correct, then you will get only one title. You could change the title as title = filename. But then also you will have the same description, because your lazy client has added only one description. :)

Comment: @naveen: Yes, Tim is correct and I agree with you also. I guess making them edit and update it on runtime will be a good option then. :) IF there is any other way of doing that let me know ?